# JavaScript / ESLint Rules in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sapui5, eslint, sap-web-ide

I want to transform this method, to fully apply to ESLint rules in SAP WEB IDE:

```
getBase64Promise: function (file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    // <-- 
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = () => {                  // <--
                let encoded = reader.result.replace("data:", "").replace(/^.*;base64,/, "");  // <--
                if ((encoded.length % 4) > 0) {
                    encoded += '='.repeat(4 - (encoded.length % 4));
                }
                resolve(encoded);
            };
            reader.onerror = error => reject(error); // <--
        });
},
```

[image]

ESLint fails with these rules:

- parenthesized pattern using "=>" should be replaced
- also "let" should be replaced

Could anyone help? I tried some things but it does not work at all:

```
getBase64Promise: function (file) { 
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload(function () {
            var encoded = reader.result.replace("data:", "").replace(/^.*;base64,/, "");
            if ((encoded.length % 4) > 0) {
                encoded += "=".repeat(4 - (encoded.length % 4));
            }
            resolve(encoded);
        });

        reader.onerror(function () {
            reject(reader.error);
        });
  });
},
```

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Yeah, might be editor-specific (WEB IDE from SAP), but I can only see error messages and not the underlying ESLint rules in detail. sorry. But I know when replacing all "=>" and "lets" it does not show any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=>` or arrow function is a short cut to create an anonymous function. It's also a way of binding the current scope to a function without having to explicitly add `.bind(this)`.

You can replace it fairly easily by changing this:

```
(params) => {
```

to

```
function(params) {
```

So something like

```
getBase64Promise: function(file) { 
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload(function() {
            var encoded = reader.result.replace("data:", "").replace(/^.*;base64,/, "");
            if ((encoded.length % 4) > 0) {
                encoded += "=".repeat(4 - (encoded.length % 4));
            }
            resolve(encoded);
        });

        reader.onerror(function() {
            reject(reader.error);
        });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I replaced `function` to `arrow function` and obsolete `var` to `let` or `const`:

```
getBase64Promise: (file) => { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload(() => {
            let encoded = reader.result.replace("data:", "").replace(/^.*;base64,/, "");
            if ((encoded.length % 4) > 0) {
                encoded += "=".repeat(4 - (encoded.length % 4));
            }
            resolve(encoded);
        });

        reader.onerror(() => {
            reject(reader.error);
        });
  });
},
```

Comment: don't get me wrong, but this is nearly the same as my original version?

Comment: No, first one you have not arrow function.

Comment: as I've written, I want to get rid of arrow functions, not having more ;-)

Comment: var is not obsolete, and having let, const or other es6 syntax in your code will break older browsers that enterprises are often still running (webide does not transpile, sadly)